Ansible WinRM error and kerberos authentication failure error
Ansible playbook is trying to execute powershell script in remote windows server using win_shell module with the user (AD user). This is configured as Jenkins freestyle job. Job fails with below error on random occurrences and many times subsequent schedules complete successfully.
Actual error:

[WARNING]: ERROR DURING WINRM SEND INPUT - attempting to recover:
Jenkins job hangs when this error occurs.

"msg": "kerberos: , plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server"
Sometimes if fails with this error.


Could not conclude what is causing this issue? Is this a bug from ansible?
I am using Ansible 2.9.10 version, python 3.6.8 version, Remote windows server 2016 standard edition.

please update here if you find fix for it. Since, it's adhoc failure you can implement a retry logic on failure. Also, may be due to Kerberos. Kerberos is time-sensitive; all systems involved must be synchronized to within a few minutes of each other. This is because tickets are only valid for a specific time period, and discrepancies in time can lead to authentication failures.
